# rust async trait fn taking parameter of type Vec<T> has error T may not live long enough

Tags: rust

The following code does not compile due to `parameter type T may not live long enough`

```rust
#[async_trait]
trait Foo<T>: Send + Sync {
    async fn foo(&self, x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>;
}

#[async_trait]
trait Bar<T>: Send + Sync {
    async fn bar(&self, x: T) -> T;
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T, U> Foo<T> for U
where
    U: Bar<Vec<T>>,
    T: Send + Sync,
{
    async fn foo(&self, x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
        self.bar(x).await
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is provide an auto implementation of trait `Foo` when `Bar<Vec<T>>` is already implemented. This works when methods are not async. The compiler recommends using a lifetime parameter but I've not been able to figure out which lifetimes need to be linked is there a solution to this?

I'd also be very interested in why this is the case for async functions.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75628690/edit) your question to include the full error message from `cargo check` (not from an IDE: those are well known to hide important parts of the error messages).

Comment: Nit: The bound `T: Send + Sync` is not needed.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the compiler. I would report it. A minimal example without `async-trait`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59b7ded6a4a5f4ff626c4fd43b624a27.